# Wifi USB for Windows Server 2008 32 bit non R2

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am on a closed network (No Internet access) and am trying to temporarily connect via Wifi (USB) to activate the OS. I was unable to active this dinosaur OS via telephone and want to avoid shipping a 1U server to corporate just for this activation.

Long and short. I am trying to source an adapter for this use. I do have a RealTek RL8188EU Wireless LAN 802.11n adapter, but no luck installing drivers for Windows Server 2008. I DO have the Wireless LAN Service installed. Any help or direction greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, I would try another adapter sadly, if the driver is incompatible, as 2008 is really old and EOL, as such find a older adapter.

Comment: Probably a much older adapter, the kind most people have already thrown away. You can also try an Ethernet-WiFi client bridge such as was popular a decade ago when gaming consoles like the Xbox only supported wired network connections. You can find these for around $10 USD online.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a spare/old WiFi router that can be configured in client mode, then you can tell it to join your WiFi network and bridge it with its Ethernet ports.  Then if you plug the server into the router via Cat5, the server will behave as if its onboard NIC is connected to a normal wired network when it'll actually be on WiFi.

This way you don't need any drivers or special configuration of the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to tether an android device and share Wifi via this.  No device drivers needed.  Thanks for considered responses to my question!

Comment: What is "this"?